# Redis returns: ERR Protocol error: unbalanced quotes in request

Tags: redis, software-distribution, redis-cluster

I am trying to import file.csv file. I used cat file.csv |redis-cli --pipe.
However, it returns an error message:
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...

```
ERR unknown command `PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked`, with args beginning with:
ERR Protocol error: unbalanced quotes in request
No replies for 30 seconds: exiting.
errors: 3, replies: 2
```

What is the problem? Could you give some feedback or hit to solve the issue?

Comment: Redis doesn't speak CSV - to import the data you'll need to convert it to Redis commands. Do a quick "load csv to Redis" search in your favorite search engine to find out how to do that :)

Comment: I think the problem is with the formatting of the csv file. I loaded another source like this additional params, and it worked for me.